# Cmake reconfiguration with sanitizers added doesn't trigger ninja to recompile

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja, address-sanitizer

Let's assume a minimal top level CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
  1 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
  2 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
  3 
  4 project(stackoverflow LANGUAGES CXX C)
  5 
  6 add_executable(prog src/main.cpp)
  7 
  8 option(ENABLE_SANITIZER "Enables sanitizer" OFF)
  9 if(ENABLE_SANITIZER)
 10   target_compile_options(prog PUBLIC -fsanitize=address)
 11   target_link_options(prog PUBLIC -fsanitize=address)
 12 endif()
```

Where the option `ENABLE_SANITIZER` adds an address sanitizer to the build.

When I configure with the sanitizer with

```bash
cmake -S . -B ./build -G "Ninja Multi-Config" -DENABLE_SANITIZER=ON
```

and build with

```bash
cmake --build ./build/ --target prog
```

everything compiles as it should, but when I reconfigure with

```bash
cmake -S . -B ./build -G "Ninja Multi-Config"
```

and build it again, ninja tells me that there is nothing to do:

```
ninja: no work to do.
```

Why does this happen when I clearly removed a compile option and link option?

Comment: `INTERFACE` so, do you know what `INTERFACE` in CMake means?

Comment: Yes and I overlooked the fact that in this minimal example it will not be used for `prog` and I apologize, this is a very boiled down version of the actual functionality. In actuality  the if condition was reduced from https://github.com/aminya/project_options/blob/main/src/Sanitizers.cmake to this.
I will change it in the question. But the behavior remains when I first configure it with sanitizer and then without.

Comment: `but when I reconfigure with` You do not re-set `ENABLE_SANITIZER=OFF`, it's still on. Add a `message()` inside.

Comment: I was missing the resetting of the variable. Thanks.
If you want to make an answer out of this comment, I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a variable, it is set inside cache `CMakeCache.txt`. When you don't reset it when reconfiguring, it preserves its previous value. The `option.... OFF`, only set's the option to `OFF` if it is unset. Even `set(ENABLE_SANITIZER OFF)` will *not* set the variable if it is in cache, only `set(.... CACHE "" "" FORCE)`, refer to documentation.